# Is setView impacted by CRS change?

Tags: leaflet, proj4js

I'm using the French IGN Leaflet extension (which use Proj4Leaflet internally) to display maps with a different coordinates system (Lambert 93 and not WGS 84). I would like to know if there is a way to call setView, add a marker, ... using the same coordinates system that the one defined in the crs property (without to do the transformation manually) ?

Actually, I have the following code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>WebApplication1</title>
        <base href="~/" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet/leaflet.css" />
        <script type='text/javascript' src="lib/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet.geoportal/GpPluginLeaflet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet.geoportal/GpPluginLeaflet-src.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet.geoportal/GpPluginLeaflet-map.css" />
        <script type='text/javascript' src="lib/leaflet.geoportal/GpPluginLeaflet.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="lib/leaflet.geoportal/GpPluginLeaflet-src.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="lib/leaflet.geoportal/GpPluginLeaflet-map.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="padding:5px; width:100%;height:800px;"></div>

        <script>
            
            function go() {
                var town1 = [48.845, 2.424];
                var map = L.map('map', {
                        crs: L.geoportalCRS.EPSG2154,
                    }).setView(town1, 18);

                var layer = L.geoportalLayer.WMTS({ layer: "ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS.BDORTHO.L93" });
                layer.addTo(map);

                map.addControl(L.geoportalControl.LayerSwitcher());

                var town2= [46.7833300, 4.8500000];
                @*var town2= [841126, 6633116];*@
                var marker = L.marker(town2);
                marker.addTo(map);

                map.setView(town2, 18, L.geoportalCRS.EPSG2154); 
            }   

            Gp.Services.getConfig({ apiKey: "jhyvi0fgmnuxvfv0zjzorvdn", onSuccess: go });

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But as you can see, the setView and the add of a marker is done using the WGS84 system coordinates. I would like to be able to do it using the same system that the one defined in crs.
I can transform the coordinates manually but I expected that Proj4Leaflet would do it automatically.

Could you tell me if there is a way to do it or not ?